# Incremental query in DBT based on current month with Jinja

Tags: jinja2, dbt

I am trying to implement a incremental query in DBT using Jinja.

Considering there are tables getting created every month in warehouse with year and month suffix and I need to write a logic to union the new table which gets created every month to execute the DBT model.
Below is the code which I have started with

```
#initialize the months in a list
{% set months= ['03','04','05','06','07','08','09','10','11','12','01','02'] %}

#first select query for Feb month of 2022
SELECT *, '2022-02-01' AS ref_month
FROM source_table_2022_02

#initilalize year variable to 2022
{% set year= namespace(items=2022) %}

#loop through the months to generate dynamic query for upcoming months
{% for month in months %}

   #if month is Jan increment the year
   {% if month == '01' %}
    {% set year.items = year.items + 1 %}
   {% endif %}

    UNION ALL 
    
    SELECT *, '{{ year.items }}-{{ month }}-01' AS ref_month
    FROM source_table_{{ year.items }}_{{ month }}

{% endfor %}
```

output of above logic is as below

```
SELECT *, '2022-02-01' AS ref_month
FROM source_table_2022_02

UNION ALL

SELECT *, '2022-03-01' AS ref_month
FROM source_table_2022_03

UNION ALL

SELECT *, '2022-04-01' AS ref_month
FROM source_table_2022_04

.
.
.

UNION ALL

SELECT *, '2023-02-01' AS ref_month
FROM source_table_2023_02
```

I need help in stopping the for loop when we reach the current month i.e Dec(because there is no current_month method in Jinja and I need to implement this logic in DBT models.sql file and not a python file), instead of looping through the upcoming months.

Note: as mentioned earlier the source table gets created every month with year and month suffix

I also want to continue the loop after 2023 Feb in the upcoming months. Current logic stops immediately after the list iteration ends i.e 2023 Feb

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Would you consider installing the commonly used `dbt-utils` package?

If so, they have a macro called [get_relations_by_pattern](https://github.com/dbt-labs/dbt-utils/tree/0.9.6/#get_relations_by_pattern-source) and another called [union_relations](https://github.com/dbt-labs/dbt-utils/tree/0.9.6/#get_relations_by_pattern-source).

These could be used to solve your problem as follows:

```sql
{% set monthly_relations = dbt_utils.get_relations_by_pattern('my_schema', 'source_table_%') %}

    SELECT *
      FROM {{ dbt_utils.union_relations(relations = monthly_relations) }}
```

Note that a new field `_dbt_source_relation` will be added, listing the original table name. You'll be able to parse the month and year from this.